# How to modify the command line arguments before getopt()

Tags: php, command-line-interface, getopt

PHP's getopt() doesn't allow separating argument and its optional value with a space, one needs to either separate with '=' or not separate:

```
# test.php uses getopt('a::')
> php test.php -a 3 // incorrect
> php test.php -a=3 // correct
> php test.php -a3 // correct
```

But on the other hand you can use space to separate argument and its required value (one specified as getopt('a:') ). For the sake of consistency and intuitiveness of using spaces, I'd like to correct the command line before it gets processed by getopt() - I have a regexp that replaces '-abc bc' with '-abc=bc'.

But turns out that modifying $argv has no effect on getopt(). I've done some testing with this script:

```
# t.php
<?php
var_dump($argv);
$argv = array();
var_dump($argv);
var_dump(getopt('a'));
?>

> php t.php -a

array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "t.php"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "-a"
}
array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  'a' =>
  bool(false)
}
```

So, there was proper $argv, I've rewritten it to empty array and still getopt() acted like nothing happened.

**Questions:**

1. where getopt() gets its input from?
2. how do I modify this input before getopt() parses it?

Comment: Looking at PHP source code, it seems that `argc` and `argv` are retrieved from the Zend engine when you call `getopt`, so changing the globals won't affect its behavior. Check this out: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4264. Anyway, I'm almost sure you can't change that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at PHP source code, it seems that `argc` and `argv` are retrieved directly from the Zend engine when you call `getopt`, so changing the globals won't affect its behavior. You can check the source code for `getopt` here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4264.

Anyway, I'm almost sure you can't change that input.

Answer (score 0):

Following comment from Gustavo, I ditched getopt() and created my own custom parser. It's part of greater code library I couldn't post here as it's too much code. I'll post the relevant methods and I think you'll be able to fill the gaps should you need such solution:

```
public function parse()
{ 
    $i = 1;
    $max = count($GLOBALS['argv'])-1;
    while ($i <= $max) {
        // Disallow arguments like '---any', '--s' and '-long'
        $argName = $this->getArgumentName($GLOBALS['argv'][$i]);
        if ($argName !== false) {

            // Allow only previously defined arguments
            if (\array_key_exists($argName, $this->args)) {
                // Disallow arguments with empty values like '-s ""'
                if (($i < $max) && $GLOBALS['argv'][$i+1]=='') {
                    throw new SyntaxException("Empty values are not allowed", SyntaxException::BAD_SYNTAX);
                }
                // if argument without value then set it to true
                elseif ($i == $max || ($this->getArgumentName($GLOBALS['argv'][$i+1]) !== false)) {
                    $this->args[$argName]->setValue(true);
                    $i++;
                }
                // if argument with value then assign it the value
                else {
                    $this->args[$argName]->setValue($GLOBALS['argv'][$i+1]);
                    $i+=2;
                }
            } else throw new SyntaxException("Unexpected argument `$argName`", SyntaxException::UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT);
        } else throw new SyntaxException("Wrong syntax of `{$GLOBALS['argv'][$i][0]}` argument", SyntaxException::BAD_SYNTAX);
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function getArgumentName($str)
{
    $name = \preg_replace('/(?:^-([\w\d])$)|(?:^--([\w\d][\w\d_?!.:-]+)$)/', '$1$2', $str,1);
    if (\is_null($name)) {
        throw new LogicException("Error in regexp with `$str` string");
    }
    return ($str == $name) ? false : $name;
}
```

About the gaps: those Exceptions aren't from SPL, they are my custom Exception hierarchy. I did it so that exception code would be script' return code too.
Also, $this->args is a collection of Argument-type objects capable of holding argument type/behavior, name, value, validators and such.